# load images from javascript

Tags: grails, resources

In my Grails app, I have a dir `web-app/images/carousel/slides` that contains files such as:

- foo.png
- foo.thumbnail.png
- bar.png
- bar.thumbnail.png

My app is using the resources Grails plugin, and the main images are loaded in a GSP using one of it's tags:

```
<r:img file="carousel/slides/foo.png"/>
```

which generates:

```
<img src="/myapp/static/images/carousel/slides/foo.png">
```

I attempt to load the thumbnail images from JavaScript by constucting a path such as `/myapp/static/images/carousel/slides/foo.thumbnail.png`. But when I attempt to display one of these images, I get a 404.

Similarly, if enter the following path in the browser's address bar

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/static/images/carousel/slides/foo.png
```

the image displays correctly, but if I enter

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/static/images/carousel/slides/foo.thumbnail.png
```

I get a 404. Why are my thumbnail images not available at the same path at runtime, given that they're in the same source directory? I suspect the answer has something to do with the fact that the main images are loaded using the resources framework whereas I attempt to load the thumbnails from JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You mostly answered your own question: if you don't reference the images using resources in some way, then they don't get processed.

Your best bet is to create a resources module that contains a list of all the images.  The add this resource to the page.

```
// grails-app/conf/CarouselResource.groovy
modules = {
    carousel {
        resource url:'/images/carousel/foo.jpg'
        resource url:'/images/carousel/foo.thumbnail.jpg'
        ...
    }
}
```

then in your GSP

```
<r:require module="carousel"/>
```

Now, the module description is a DSL, so you might be able to use some sort of file loop to automatically add all the files, but I'm not 100% sure how.  You also might try something like `'/images/carousel/**'`, but the docs don't say if that would work or not.

---

Also, I should mention, if you use any of the caching-based resources plugins, this won't help.  You will then need to manually call `r.img()` and set it within your JavaScript, something like this (if it works):

```
<r:script>
    var images = [
        '${r.img(...)}'
    ];
</r:script>
```

This is because the URLs generated using, for example, *cached-resources*, are often hashes of the file content to allow for long-term caching.  They usually are only indirectly related to the original filename.

---

Update based on comment below:

To load a common JS remotely, but include the images, you could do something like this.  Realize, I don't know your carousel code, and you will almost certainly have to modify the carousel library to handle these changes.

```
<r:script>
    window.carouselImages = [
        {
            image: '${r.external(url:'images/carousel/image1.jpg'}.encodeAsJavaScript();}',
            thumbnail: '${r.external(url:'images/carousel/image1.thumbnail.jpg'}.encodeAsJavaScript();}'
        },
        ...
    ];
</r:script>
<r:resource url="js/carousel.js"/>
```

Then in `carousel.js` you reference `window.carouselImages` to get your array of images.  It also should be possible it flip the order, and use some method within `carousel.js` to add images, like this:

```
<r:script>
    carousel.addImage('${r.external(url:'images/carousel/image1.jpg'}.encodeAsJavaScript();}', '${r.external(url:'images/carousel/image1.thumbnail.jpg'}.encodeAsJavaScript();}');
    ...
</r:script>
```

You can improve this by looping over the file list instead of encoding each image explicitly (and example was given in the JIRA I posted below).

---

Finally, if you aren't going to use any of the caching or file manipulation plugins (so the files always end up at the same URL), you could just simply loop over the files from within the controller or a service method, calling `r.img()` on each one.  This would ensure that they are copied to the `static` directory.  The return value from `r.img()` can be ignored.

Comment: OK, I tried using `resource url:'foo/*.png'` and that threw an error.  It looks like all resources have to be expressed individually.  That would be a nice feature for this plugin later.

Comment: Found this JIRA about directory-based resources if you want to vote: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPRESOURCES-90

Comment: In my case I'm trying to refer to the resource from .js file, not a `<script>` block in a GSP, so I can't use `<r:img>`. Based on what you've said above it seems that if I'm using the resources plugin for managing .css and .js, then I'm pretty much forced to declare modules for my images too. This is a PITA, particularly because wildcards aren't supported and I don't want the resources plugin to do anything with my images. Thanks for the reply, and the JIRA link.

Comment: You can combine the two: load the common JS remotely, but define the list using an embedded script.  You could store them on some global property in the embedded script, like `window.carouselImages = ...`.  You don't necessarily even have to use those items - they just need to be processed by the resources plugin.

Comment: I'm not really following whatever you're proposing in that last comment. If you have the time/inclination could you edit your post to show an example? Thanks.

Comment: I guess I mustn't be explaining my problem very well. I tried to emphasise that there is no GSP here, but 3 times you've posted code examples using the <r:script> GSP tag. I'm trying to load the image from a .js file, there is no GSP called after the controller execution complete. Anyway, thanks for your help

Comment: You aren't making sense.  There's got to be some code *somewhere* that generates HTML of some sort.  I'm saying, put the image reference in whatever generates the HTML.  I even explain a different alternative in the last section, which avoids outputting the image at all.  That could be used from within a controller.  No matter what, if you want the images included in the static folder, you **have to tell resources about them**.  I actually gave you 3 completely different solutions.

Comment: This is why I hate grails, I think I should just quit and sell lemonade, I prefer that over dealing why lame implementations. they are just static files for Christ sake. I miss Yii T_T

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5's data-* Attribute

```
<element data-*="somevalue">
```

Here is an example if your image is located at /grails-app/assets/images:

In page (i.e. index.gsp) you have to add the following:

And from the javascript all you have to do is:

```
<script>
    var calImg = document.getElementById('calendar-icon').getAttribute('data-calendaricon');
</script>
```

Pretty straightforward, moreover it is a clean approach :)