# How can I access images from Javascript using Grails Asset-Pipeline plugin?

Tags: javascript, grails, asset-pipeline

I have just upgraded to Grails 2.4 and am using the Asset-Pipeline1.8.7 plugin.  I am wondering how to access the images from Javascript.  I am using the Google Maps Javascript V3 API and need to set some marker icons in Javascript.  Is there a way to create some Javascript vars on a GSP using the  tag and then access the file in my app.js code?  If that is not possible, how do a reference the compiled images in assets?

Comment: Do you have used resource plugin taglib in that javascripts?
Or something like `${resource(dir:"", file:"")}`?

Comment: I have used the Resources Plugin, but I can't figure out a way to get access to the image locations in the app.js file?  With Grails 2.4 I am using the Asset-Pipeline Manager but same issue.  I saw an example where they declared a JS Var within the GSP using the g:javascript tag, but my app.js still could not reference this variable.

Comment: With the resource plugin taglib and resource method (which is native grails method not from plugin) your root start from WEB-APPS.
With asset-pipeline plugin taglib and assetPath method the root starts from grails-app/assets.
Look at my examples below.
The file located in the folder
`./grails-app/assets/stylesheets/style.css`
And I use it in a code:
`assetPath(src: "stylesheets/style.css")`
or in as the tag in view:
`<asset:stylesheet src="style.css"/>`

The same with resource

Answer (score 20):

You could define a globally available object that holds the root-path to your assets dir and use this to build-up URLs to your assets.
Add this snippet to your layouts head-section

```
<g:javascript>
    window.grailsSupport = {
        assetsRoot : '${ raw(asset.assetPath(src: '')) }'
    };
</g:javascript>
```

Then use it elsewhere like this:

```
<g:javascript>
    var pathToMyImg = window.grailsSupport.assetsRoot + 'images/google_maps_marker.png';
</g:javascript>
```

**Update 2015-08-06**

While checking the release notes of the [asset-pipeline plugin](https://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/guide/releases.html) I noticed that non-digest versions of assets are no longer stored in the WAR-file. This would mean that my proposed solution breaks when the application is deployed as a WAR:

> May 31, 2015
>   2.2.3 Release - No longer storing non digest versions in war file, cutting overhead in half. Also removed Commons i/o dependency. Faster byte stream.

This means that you have to explicitly define all your images beforehand and are no longer able to construct the path dynamically in your scripts:

```
<g:javascript>
    window.grailsSupport = {
        myImage1 : '${assetPath(src: 'myImage1.jpg')}',
        myImage2 : '${assetPath(src: 'myImage2.jpg')}'
    };
</g:javascript>
```

**Update 2016-05-25**

It is now possible to configure if non-digest versions of the assets are included in the built war-file by setting `grails.assets.skipNonDigests` (default is `false`):

> It is normally not necessary to turn off 'skipNonDigests'. Tomcat will automatically still serve files by non digest name and will copy them out using storagePath via the `manifest.properties` alias map. This simply cuts storage in half. However, if you are attempting to do things like upload to a cdn outside of the cdn-asset-pipeline plugin and via the contents of 'target/assets'. This may still be useful.

Note that you still might use the proposed solution to define all required images beforehand to work around caching issues in the browser (as the digest-version of the asset has its content-hash in the filename).

Comment: Good answer, but I don't have enough reputation points to up vote

Answer (score 10):

Yes you can by putting a `${assetPath(src: 'img.png')}` in your gsp

Comment: This, by far, is the simplest and most straight-forward answer.

Comment: @davydotcom, How can I use ${assetPath(src: 'img.png')} on javascript file o stylesheet file ?
I'm using grails:
    assets:
        url: https://assets.domain.com/
        storagePath: /opt/domain/assets/

Answer (score 7):

I don't know what the ideal solution is in your case but a solution might be:

1. Use relative paths like '../assets/use-control.png' in your js code.
2. Add the img in your dom and reference it from your js code.
3. Add a `data-imgpath="${asset.assetPath(src: 'use-control.png')}"` attribute on an appropriate element in your dom and use this link.

Comment: This answer will work, I can't up-vote it since I don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: I like this answer as well, but I can't up vote it since I don't have enough reputation points yet either.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use HTML5's data-* Attribute.
I've explained a bit further here:
[load images from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780395/load-images-from-javascript/25406419#25406419)